# SQL db row,1 cell containing multiple image locations, query

Tags: php

How can I process a sql cell ($afbeeldingen) containing multiple image locations?
The vehicle table holds the column "images"(or in dutch language "afbeeldingen"), and for one vehicle there can be multiple imagelinks in "images", urls are seperated with a ","

I would like to output

```
<img src=imagelocation>
```

for each location stored in the single cell.

```
function toon_voertuigen()
{
    include ('dbconn.php');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicles";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Couldn’t execute query.");
    $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "<table>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++)
    {
        $n = $i + 1; //add 1 so numbers don’t start with 0
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        extract($row);
        echo "<tr>\n
            <td>$n.</td>\n

            <td>
              $images  //Contains multiple imagelinks, this needs to be exploded to <img src=$images>
            </td>
            </tr>\n";
    }
}


echo "</table>\n";
```

How can i use the explode function on $images to echo for each imageurl

```
<img src=$images>
```

Comment: Not clear..can you elaborate a bit more..

Comment: edited, maybe a bit more clear i hope

Comment: It doesn't make sense to make declare a function and then call it, but you are a beginner. ;)

Comment: Its just to have a complete question, ofcourse the function is gonna be in a different fileresource

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how those image locations are written in that particular column. If they're separated by ";" then you can use $newarray = explode(";",$afbeeldingen) .. This will give you an array of all the parts separated by ";"... this is just an example..it could be that those image locations are separated by " " or by a "/" .. so you use the character that separates them..then you iterate on the array and you can either divide them on different  or in the same  but like put them  in  or

Comment: So basically, what you're looking for is the explode() function. Just let us know the way those locations are stored in the cell, a sample value or value(s) would definitely be helpful and you SHOULD definitely have added that in your initial question.

Comment: I need to get used to php scripting i guess.. 
$afbeelding = explode(',', $afbeeldingen);
  foreach($afbeeldingen as $foto_nr => $foto_url);
echo $afbeelding;

Comment: So it worked? Usually you should always do a quick search on the many many functions available in php .. there are lot of functions that handle strings, arrays, arrays->to->strings, strings->to->arrays, arrays->unique_arrays. etc.. all these functions definitely come in handy when one is faced with an issue.. Always look at the tools available and see if something works out.

Comment: it does work, i use something like it for downloading images from a $_post array with file_get_contents
$fotos = explode(',', $_POST['afbeeldingen']);
  foreach($fotos as $foto_nr => $foto_url) {
   $filename = 'fotos/'. $_POST['db_id'] .'-'. $foto_nr .'.jpg';
   
   $imgdata = file_get_contents($foto_url);
   file_put_contents($filename, $imgdata);

Comment: Cool, can you mark the above answer as correct then :) thanks

Comment: I did, but i still dunno how to extract the imagelocations from the dbcell $images

$vehicles ="SELECT * FROM vehicles";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$vehicles) or die ("Couldn’t execute query.");
$nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for ($i=0;$i<$nrows;$i++)
{
$n = $i + 1; #add 1 so numbers don’t start with 0
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
extract($row);
$fotos = explode(',', $images);

Comment: Ahh well, when i test the explode function it works as it should,
`$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
extract($row);
$images = explode(',', $images);
print_r($images);` outputs the array, i probably have a syntax errror somewhere.. need some rest maybe ;)